# Unable to change any of the settings of ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I installed new Ubuntu OS for which i created a administrator account. I was unable to change any of the settings in settings option of Ubuntu 18.04. I am able to change the settings when i created the another account. I am not able to change the settings from the previous accounts.

Comment: What settings ? What commands or app's are you trying to run, what parameters are you trying to change ?

Comment: I am not able to change the size the of Icon size of dock, Unable to add the items to dock. Even if i set the apps to fav it doesnt get added. Every setting i am unable to do from my account

Comment: Might be account is locked to change any settings. how to remove it

Answer (score -1):

I solved the issue by deleting .config

Step1:

```
cd .config
```

Step2:

```
rm -R *

suraj@suraj:~$ cd .config

suraj@suraj:~/.config$ ls
 dconf                      gnome-session   menus              update-notifier
 enchant                    goa-1.0         mimeapps.list      user-dirs.dirs
 eog                        google-chrome  'MongoDB Compass'   user-dirs.locale
 evolution                  gtk-3.0         nautilus           yelp
 gedit                      ibus            pulse
 gnome-initial-setup-done   libreoffice     Slack
suraj@suraj:~/.config$ rm -R *
```